# IGN (In Game Name) Crash

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I changed my username for Minecraft the other day and logged out then back in of my Mojang account to authenticate it, yet I still cannot join other servers. The only solution provided for these situations is to log out and back in, although I have already done this and my name was not changed just the same.

If anyone is able to help me that would be great, as I had a similar experience that took a week to recalibrate my IGN. :(

Comment: There appear to be important details missing from this question, since the title is about crashing, but the body doesn't explain the crash, only mentions that you can't connect to servers (and further, doesn't explain what happens when you try).

Answer (score 1):

If you can start up minecraft, you've logged in properly. (unless you're playing in offline mode). Some servers haven't yet adopted the new UUID system, which might stop you from joining their server. If you play on a server with a whitelist, ask them to add your new username to the list.